# keyboard.add_hotkey stops working after opening taskmanager

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, keyboard, hotkeys

I'm using the python module keyboard to create a hotkey, and it works like its supposed to until I open task manager, after that the hotkey just stops working, creating a new one doesn't help, no hotkeys work after task manager gets opened.

```
import keyboard

def hello():
    print('hello world!')

keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+p', hello, args=())

while True:
    pass
```

the above code is just an example to replicate the issue, i import the module, create a hotkey, then create a infinite while loop so the program doesn't exit, and the hotkey works *until* you open task manager.

The reason for why I need to use add_hotkey and not any other function is because Im going to use it for a much larger program, and add_hotkey doesn't slow the app down, but of course, it can break and then only a restart of the program will fix it.

I have tried a lot of stuff already, that have partially worked, re-importing the module works great, but I dont have a way of knowing the right time of re-importing it, and I could also run the program as admin, that solves the issue as well, but I don't want the program to be ran as admin only because of a hotkey function.

Answer (score 1):

I was running some more tests and I found an answer (its amazing how easy it is to answer your own question after posting a question online somewhere).

Basically my program doesn't have admin permissions so the keyboard module pauses when task manager is launched, which I knew it did but I thought it broke the whole module. What actually happens is that I launch my task manager by pressing ctrl shift esc, the keys get registered in the program, then manager launches, program pauses, and when I let go off the keys the program doesn't register that.

So whenever I was pressing alt + p the module thought I was pressing ctrl shift esc alt p.

To fix it you just press all three keys but not at the same time to refresh it.

I haven't tried it yet but what I'll do is simply make my program clear all the keys after any keyboard press, that way the hotkey will still function and after ctrl shift esc it will hang, then unpause and clear the leftover inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a hard time because I had the same problem.
And I finally found a solution!
It's using 'keyboard.hook_key'.

Here is my code.

```
import keyboard


temp = False

def switch(e):
    global temp
    if 'down' in e:
        temp = True
    else:
        temp = False

def check(e):
    global temp
    if temp and 'down' in e:
        print('It works!!')

keyboard.hook_key('alt', lambda e: switch(str(e)))
keyboard.hook_key('p', lambda e: check(str(e)))
keyboard.wait()
```

'hook_key' only detects 'Down' and 'Up' events of a single key on the keyboard, so it will work normally even after the task manager is turned on.